# How to find identical items in a Source

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a Source like this:

```
1 | red | light | 10
2 | blue | dark | 20
1 | brown | light | 2
1 | red | light | 10
20 | grey | dark | 200
```

I want to find out (`true / false`) whether there are any identical items in the source. In the above stream `1 | red | light | 10` would be identical. This stream could be very big over 2M records. I can return `true` soon as the identical item is found (i.e. in the example above, we can avoid reading `20 | grey | dark | 200`).

What is the best way to do this? I tried reading the entire source into a `List(String)` and ran distinct on it. This works ok, however, for large sources I start receiving a OOM error.

```
val restResult: Future[immutable.Seq[Color]] =
  mySource(ctx)
    .drop(1)
    .via(framing("\n"))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .map(_.trim)
    .map(s => ColorParser(s))
    .collect {
      case Right(color) => color
    }
    .runWith(Sink.seq)
```

Comment: How about using a stream to read the CSV line by line and appending the elements recursively into an accumulator and do the check in the accumulator as and when you read new elements?

Comment: i am reading the elements line by line (code provided). I'm not familiar with the concept of accumulator. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222495/reading-a-large-file-using-akka-streams

Comment: Not sure if Akka-streams is the right tool for this. You can easily get an StackOverflowException if you don't find any duplicates. Spark or Flink looks like better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of examining identical list of colors :

```
case class Color(n: String, name: String, lightOrDark: String, n2: String)

val k1 = Color("1", "red", "light", "10")
val k2 = Color("1", "blue", "dark", "11")
val k3 = Color("1", "orange", "dark", "11")
val k4 = Color("1", "red", "light", "10")
val k5 = Color("1", "red", "dark", "200")

println(k1.hashCode() == k2.hashCode())
println(k1.hashCode() == k4.hashCode())

val set = mutable.Set.empty[Int]

val colorList = List(k1, k2, k3, k4, k5)

val restResult = 
Source
.fromIterator(colorList.iterator _)
  .map { color =>
    val hashCode = color.hashCode()
    val res = !set.contains(hashCode)
    set += hashCode
    res
  }.takeWhile(identity, inclusive = true)
  .runWith(Sink.last)


restResult.onComplete {
  case Success(value) =>
    println(value)
    system.terminate()

  case Failure(e) =>
    e.printStackTrace()
    system.terminate()
}
```

the whole source is [here](https://github.com/hamednourhani/scala-playground/blob/d2132244e3dad149c4c0b4694d337ca7fd95e529/src/main/scala/ir/itstar/playground/akka/stream/StreamIdenticalElements.scala)